# How to allow usage of underscore in i18n?

Tags: internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

I am using React and i18next.

We are using `graphql` and `react-i18next` and would like to share the same enum across language used and the graphql schema.

Since we want 2x2 letter local, and `graphql` to not support hyphen in enum. We decided to go with `EN_US`.

The problem is, when using `EN_US` format in i18n

```
i18n
  .use(ICU)
  .use(HttpApi)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    fallbackLng: 'EN_US',
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
    resources: {
      'EN_US': { core: EN_US }
    },
    ns: ['core'],
    load: 'currentOnly',
    debug: true,
    lng: 'EN_US',
    supportedLngs: ['EN_US'],
  });
```

When using `EN_US` I get spammed with

> i18next::pluralResolver: no plural rule found for: EN_US

and my ICU translations don't work anymore. `so they appear like this {{count, plural, =0{アカウント} =1{アカウント} other{アカウント}}` using `en-US` works and all my ICU are correctly translated.

So it looks like that using unconventional `EN_US` report warning and break ICU, while using normal `en-US` works.

Is there a way to make it work with `EN_US` ? Or do I need to convert the language to `en-US` when using i18n?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you're not bound to any specific language code format, but if you want to make use of all the in built language features, like proper pluralization and correct fallback resolution, we strongly suggest to use the following iso norm:
lng-(script)-REGION-(extensions)

i.e.
en, en-US or en-GB
zh, zh-HK or zh-Hant-HK
Other examples are listed here: [https://www.iana.org/assignments/language-tags/language-tags.xhtml​](https://www.iana.org/assignments/language-tags/language-tags.xhtml%E2%80%8B)
And more information about the format can be found here: [https://www.w3.org/International/articles/language-tags/​](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/language-tags/%E2%80%8B)

Comment: I read that, but how do I remove the alert message ? Also, since I use count variable in my ICU string, they do not work because of this.